# Python 3.62 ElementTree . Управля́ющие си́мволы при переводе в строку не работают

Tags: python, кодировка

Есть небольшой код в котором quests_templates[0] это ET.Element

```
ET.dump(quests_templates[0])
print( ET.tostring(quests_templates[0]) )
print("The end")
```

dump выводит файл в нормальном формате XML

```
...<QuestType>KillAndLoot</QuestType>
  <QuestClass xsi:type="KillAndLootEasyQuestClass">
    <HotSpots>
    <Vector3 X="-8928.41" Y="-118.0785" Z="82.17709" />
    <Vector3 X="-8945.35" Y="-138.4347" Z="83.69251" />...
```

Однако  print( ET.tostring(quests_templates[0]) ) выводит текст с управляющими символами.

```
<QuestType>KillAndLoot</QuestType>\n      <QuestClass xsi:type="KillAndLootEasyQuestClass">\n        <HotSpots>\n        <Vector3 X="-8928.41" Y="-118.0785" Z="82.17709" />\n        <Vector3 X="-8945.35" Y="-138.4347" Z="83.69251" />\n
```

Собственно, как это исправить? Хотелось бы сохранить все в нормальном формате

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Изменил на:

```
ET.dump(quests_templates[0])
print( str(ET.tostring(quests_templates[0]),'utf-8') )
print("The end ")
```

Теперь нормально.

Comment: Перед тем, как так трогательно расстаться, отметьте ответ как принятый, если он действительно ответил на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @0xdb емнип, для самоответов галочка становится доступна только через два дня